# Angular2 whenStable() not working with observable?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testing, observable

I'm running an http call (using obervable) in the ngOnInit method from one Angular2 component:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.descriptorService.generateDescriptors(new Server());
     this.fetchData();
}

fetchData () {
  console.log('Starting Http call');
  this.dataService.listAll(Server).subscribe(
     servers=>{console.log('Http Call done');this.listServers=servers},
     error=>console.log(error)
  );
}
```

with the following dataService.listAll():

```
listAll(zeClass:typeof Model): Observable<T[]> {
  console.log('Http call begin');
  return this.http.get(this.calculateUrl(zeClass))
    .map(this.extractData)
    .map((jsonArray)=>{
       let data:Array<ModelInterface>=new Array<ModelInterface>();
       if (isArray (jsonArray)) {
             console.log('Http call in');
         ...
       return data;
     })
    .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

When I run the following unit test for this component (http is mockedup with InMemoryWebApiModule) :

```
it('should display the list of servers', async(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  console.log('Before whenStable():'+fixture.isStable());
  fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
    console.log('In whenStable()');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let de:Array<DebugElement> = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('md-list-item'));

    expect(de.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
  });
console.log('After whenStable():'+fixture.isStable());
}));
```

I then get the following log in the console:

```
 LOG: 'Starting Http call'
 LOG: 'Http call begin'
 LOG: 'Before whenStable():false'
 LOG: 'After whenStable():false'
```

You can see the test code inside whenStable() is not run at all...
Why ?

Comment: Why do you think that's not working? It's an async callback, that's what's *supposed* to happen. Have you tried using `done`?

Comment: The first line in whenstable() is a log that I never see in the console.
I saw some posts around "done" but I'm not really sure what it is

Comment: Yes, because it's asynchronous, so the test is over before the callback gets called... back. *"After whenStable"* does **not** mean after the callback runs.

Comment: yes, but isn't whenstable() supposed to wait until all async() operations are done ?

Comment: It doesn't *call the callback* until all operations are done. Please look into Jasmine's `done`, as I suggested above.

Comment: I saw the info about [done](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#jasmine-done).
It seems promising, I'll test and keep you informed.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @jonrsharpe for pointing me to the right direction.
Effectively I had to use Jasmine done and spies.

For info, here is the working test code:

```
 beforeEach(inject([GenericDataService], (dataService) => {
   spy = spyOn(dataService,'listAll').and.callThrough();
   ...
 }
```

and

```
it('should display the list of servers', done => {
  fixture.detectChanges();

  spy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.subscribe (() => {
    console.log('In spy()');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let de:Array<DebugElement> = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('md-list-item'));

    expect(de.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
    done();
    });
});
```